# Finding point on 3d model based on image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, pattern-matching, 3d-model

I'm looking for a point where to start and how to do it right. I have a 3d model of an object. On this object are special points. Another thing I have is real photo of this object with source of light 
coming from one of the points. What I want to achieve is to in some way comapre this photo and model to be able by basing on source of light to determine what specific point it is.

Which technology/library will allow me to achieve desired result and where I should start looking?

Edit:

To be more accurate. I don't have any data yet. But camera will be placed in fixed position same as metal part. This part will be rotated only in single axis. And this part have different shapes on different angles so it will be easier (I think) to match it with 3d model.

Comment: Is it possible to post an example of one object model and photo? I think this might help.

Comment: I don't have already any model or photo physically but I can say this could be a car metal part with welds on it and the photo will include light from manual welding process or light from infrared camera.

Comment: It is unclear to me what "the photo will include light" means.

Comment: I mean bright area for example or any other type of "mark" to tell which weld we looking for.

Comment: As with all image processing questions, it is pointless to even start an answer before seeing representative pictures.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier I don't have any data already. I rather asking about tools I can use to even theoretically solve this problem.

Comment: @Anwarus recomend tools is of topic here. This is more Computer vision task than machine learning (people are ususaly using OpenCV for such tasks) and without any sample images is this unanswerable (as any CV/DIP question). Also google SIFT/SURF and RANSAC they might help you with this.